# Don't work jQuery.get()

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

```
$.get('./mods/webim_offline_email.php', {firstname: $('#webim_firstname').val(), email: $('#webim_email').val(), message: $('#webim_message').val()}, function (data){
    alert(1);
    $('#webim_offline_inputs').fadeOut(200);
    $('#webim_message_div').fadeOut(200);
    $('#webim_buttons').fadeOut(200);
    $('#webim_offline_sent').fadeIn(200);
}).success(function(){
    alert("second success");
}).error(function(){
    alert("error");
}).complete(function(){
    alert("complete");
});
```

Request *.php passes, and all that is inside a function works. On the computer friend request passes too, but jQuery believes that he is not passed, the function is not passed and the `alert("error")`. Why?

Comment: Are you sure that the path is correct? `error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)` jQuery tells you the reason.

Comment: .success .error and .complete have been renamed in recent versions of jQuery. What version are you using?

Comment: @undefined sure, this work on my computer and tablet, but don't work on friend's computer

Comment: What's the error message in `errorThrown`?

Comment: @Luntegg: please answer your own question and accept it

Comment: ahh yes, you don't have enough reputation yet. if you stick around on the site, your reputation will build as you answer other people's questions.

Comment: @Nicholas, I know it, thanks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was settled. Sorry. Friends have links without port, and the answer don't came from the page.